# Global List Access Using PThreads - Pointer Issue?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pthreads

We are doing a project using threads and mutexes to simulate a bunch of clients hitting different or same bank accounts.  I have little to no C/C++ experience, and I think this issue is pointer related.  Basically I have a Client object that contains a list of transactions and a list of accounts and that is passed as a parameter to a pthread where it is sent to a processing method.

```
class Client{
public:
    list<Transaction> transactions;
    list<Account>* accounts;
    Client(list<Transaction>, list<Account>);
};

Client::Client(list<Transaction> a, list<Account> b){
transactions = a;
accounts = &b;
}

extern "C"
{
void* RunTransactions(void* arg)
{
    Client* c = static_cast<Client*>(arg);

    // while(!(*c).transactions.empty()){
        // cout << "HERE" << endl;
    // }

    cout << "Thread Before: ";
    (*(*c).accounts).front().Print();

    (*(*c).accounts).front().balance -= 25;
    (*(*c).accounts).front().balance -= 25;
    (*(*c).accounts).front().balance -= 25;

    cout << "Thread After: ";
    (*(*c).accounts).front().Print();

    // list<Transaction>* trans = static_cast<list<Transaction>*>(arg);
    // Transaction t = trans->front();
    // t.Print();

    // Test* t = static_cast<Test*>(arg);

    // (*t).Increase();
    // cout << "Thread - " << t->x << endl;

    return 0;
}
}

int main( ){

list<Account> accounts;

cout << "Accounts: ";
cin >> NumAccts;

for(long i = 0; i < NumAccts; i++){
    long tempBalance;
    cout << "Balance for Account " << i << ": ";
    cin >> tempBalance;

    accounts.push_back(Account(i, tempBalance));
}

//Test Input
pthread_t t1;
list<Transaction> tempTrans;
tempTrans.push_back(Transaction(0, 1, 100));
tempTrans.push_back(Transaction(1, 0, 50));
tempTrans.push_back(Transaction(2, 1, 222));

Client c = Client(tempTrans, accounts);

cout << "Main Before: ";
accounts.front().Print();

pthread_create(&t1, NULL, RunTransactions, &c);

pthread_join(t1, NULL);

cout << "Main After: ";
accounts.front().Print();


return 0;
}
```

What I do not understand is how I should have my threads all have access to the accounts list that is created in main?  Right now whenever I do anything with the accounts list that I pull out of the client it makes the changes in the thread, but I don't see the changes in the accounts list in main after the join.  Again, I think it has to do with the way I am either passing or accessing accounts in the Client object or in main, or possibly RunTransactions?  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you avoiding the `->` operator?

Answer (score 1):

```
Client::Client(list<Transaction> a, list<Account> b) {
```

`b` is a copy of the list being passed in, and will almost certainly be passed on the stack.  As soon as the constructor returns, your pointer is probably invalid.

You'd do better to make your Client's `accounts` an actual list rather than a pointer to one.  You don't really want to let your object hold a pointer to something that wasn't heap-allocated, or that someone else has access to.  That way lies madness.

Comment: Not to sure what you mean by "make accounts an actual list".  If I just made it a list instead of a pointer in the Client class, wouldn't it still be just a copy so all the changes would not affect the list in main?

Comment: Right.  Those kinds of side effects are usually an accident -- and even when they're not, they're a bad idea.  (It's called "action at a distance", and it's an anti-pattern.)  If you want the list after your Client's done something with it, then add methods on Client to get the list.  In general, your object should own whatever's inside it; otherwise, the caller can muck around with the object's internal state and break any invariants you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
Client::Client(list<Transaction> a, list<Account> b){
    transactions = a;
    accounts = &b;
}
```

Is basically saying: "Oh yeah, Roy, you have this list here, right, with all these accounts? Well, somebody emailed it to me, can you see where that list came from, and just store the name of who created the list? I'm sure we'll be able to get the list back from that address later."

So Roy stores the name "Waldo" in the client's profile. We all know what happened after that. He was never able to retrieve the list again when the client asked for it, sadly. If only he had made a copy of the list, or made sure that the source that created the list would not just disappear one day.